# SQL Server overlapping dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, overlapping

I need help updating a calendar table. I have 2 tables a transaction table (table T) and a calendar table (Table C). i am trying to update then calendar table with application id (`app_id`) and `emp_Id` once the dates are available, if the dates overlap it should not be updated. e.g

Table T

```
app_id  emp_id stdate      eddate      priority 
-----------------------------------------------     
1       15     2015-01-03  2015-01-05   1
2       18     2015-01-04  2015-01-06   2
```

Table C

```
dates        app_id    empid
----------------------------
2015-01-03     null    null
2015-01-04     null    null
2015-01-05     null    null
```

After the update is run the outcome should be

Table C

```
dates        app_id    empid
----------------------------
2015-01-03     1        15
2015-01-04     1        15
2015-01-05     1        15
```

Comment: Assuming dates in Table T cannot overlap, this is a simple join on `C.dates >= T.stdate AND C.dates <= T.eddate`

Comment: Do you need both `app_id` and `emp_id`? Are they both PK of table T? Or just the former? I guess `2015-01-06` will have `2 18`, right?

Comment: yes i need app_id and emp_id and they are pk in table T

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I would be inclined to do this with `apply`:

```
update c
    set app_id = t.app_id,
        empid = t.empid
    from table_c c apply
         (select top 1 t.*
          from table_t t
          where tc.dates >= t.stdate and
                tc.dates <= t.eddate
          order by t.priority
         ) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this off the top of my head, I hope it works for you:

```
UPDATE TC
SET app_id = (SELECT TOP 1 app_id FROM TABLE_T TT WHERE TC.dates BETWEEN TT.stdate AND tt.eddate ORDER BY TT.priority ASC),
empid = (SELECT TOP 1 emp_id FROM TABLE_T TT WHERE TC.dates BETWEEN TT.stdate AND tt.eddate ORDER BY TT.priority ASC)
FROM TABLE_C TC
```

You can debug this first with this query:

```
SELECT TC.*,
new_app_id = (SELECT TOP 1 app_id FROM TABLE_T TT WHERE TC.dates BETWEEN TT.stdate AND tt.eddate ORDER BY TT.priority ASC),
new_empid = (SELECT TOP 1 emp_id FROM TABLE_T TT WHERE TC.dates BETWEEN TT.stdate AND tt.eddate ORDER BY TT.priority ASC)
FROM TABLE_C TC
```

*I used `emp_id` and `empid` as in your example.*